# Add method to json output with include in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am getting info from my database

```
@teams  = Team.select(:id,:name)
```

Then, I am rendering this info with an assosiation

```
render json: @teams, include: :players
```

This produce me the following input:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Lyon Gaming",
    "players": [
          {
            "name": "Jirall",
            "position": "Superior",
          },
          {
            "name": "Oddie",
            "position": "Jungla",
          }
      ]
}
```

]

How ever I need to sort the players in an specific order (not alphabetical)

I already have the sql statement to do it; how ever I dont know how to apply this method to each association.

I am looking something like:

```
render json: @teams, (include: :players, method: custom_order)
```

But this raise me an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
render json: @teams, include: :players, methods: :custom_order
```

I'd like to add that if you will always want to return the object this way, you can add this to your model instead:

```
  def as_json(options = nil)
    super(include: :players, methods: :custom_order)
  end
```

As Adam has mentioned, active_model_serializers is good to have if your render json's start getting ugly. If the complexity doesn't grow too much, I always recommend keeping the dependencies down.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about serializers in rails(This is good practice)
Here you have a nice article about this https://www.sitepoint.com/active-model-serializers-rails-and-json-oh-my/

Then you can make something like this

app/serializers/team_serializer.rb

```
class TeamSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :ordered_players
end
```

app/controllers/teams_controller.rb

```
def index
  respond_with(Team.all.map(&TeamSerializer.method(:new)))
end
```